# Linearisation of product of two continuous variable.

Tags: qcqp

I have a quadratic constraint which I want to linearise.

$x_1x_2=0$
where $0\leqslant x_1,x_2\leqslant1$.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Maybe you can replace the constraint with "$x_1= 0$ or $x_2 = 0$"

Comment: Please suggest a way.

Comment: Would $x_1=x_2=0$ be a desirable solution? Or do you want to model that exactly one of the two variables is zero?

Answer (score -1):

The region described by $0\le x_1,x_2\le 1$ is a square and the condition $x_1x_2=0$ is equivalent to "$x_1=0$ or $x_2=0$" which restricts the solution space to the left and lower edges of the square. The smallest convex set containing these two edges is the triangle described by $x_1+x_2\le 1$.

Depending on your optimization problem (which you didn't tell us) it may be a good or a horrible idea to linearize the condition by $x_1+x_2\le 1$.

---

If this doesn't answer your question, please edit your post to clarify what you are asking for and include the full description of the optimization problem you are trying to solve or linearize.

Comment: $x_1=x_2=\frac{1}{2}$ is feasible for $\{ 0 \leq x_1,x_2 \leq 1, x_1+x_2 \leq 1\}$ but violates the original constraint $x_1 x_2 =0$. Even though you somewhat strengthen the formulation, your method does not model the intial constraint.

Comment: I didn't claim it would. Of course a triangle contains more than just two of its edges. If you want a convex set contained in $x_1x_2=0$, you are left with the origin.

Comment: I want the solution to be either of the three solutions $(x_1,x_2)=\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)\}$ without using binary constraints on $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: You can not enforce this using linear conditions. The convex hull of those three points is the triangle I described and you can't do any better using linear constraints.